# Closing JDialog leaves an empty frame

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a small problem with a JDialog, it leaves an empty frame after closing  despite everything I do. I've been trying quite long to find a solution, unfortunately, neither this

```
daughterWindow.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(validation, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

nor

```
daughterWindow.setVisible(false);
daughterWindow.dispose();
```

nor this one helped me

```
WindowAdapter adapter = (WindowAdapter)jdialog.getWindowListeners()[0];
adapter.windowClosing(new WindowEvent((Window)jdialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

most likely, because of a ClassCastException the last one throws.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame cannot be cast to java.awt.event.WindowAdapter

Here's my code, maybe someone can give me a hint.

```
    JDialog daughterWindow = new JDialog();
    daughterWindow.setModal(true);
    daughterWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    daughterWindow.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(daughterWindow.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
    JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
    File rsc = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\rsc\\");
    if(!rsc.exists()) rsc.mkdir();
    open.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\rsc\\"));
    open.setDialogTitle("Ordner mit der Datenbank auswählen");
    open.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    if(open.showOpenDialog(daughterWindow) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.FALSE);
        setValidateAccessWindowLayout(open.getSelectedFile());
        daughterWindow.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(daughterWindow, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    } else{
        UIManager.put("FileChooser.readOnly", Boolean.FALSE);
        daughterWindow.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(daughterWindow, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }

    daughterWindow.setResizable(false);
    daughterWindow.pack();
    daughterWindow.setVisible(true);
```

[And a screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5CeF.jpg)
Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
checked out the third option without apparently needless cast, but that didn't help as well.

```
WindowListener adapter = daughterWindow.getWindowListeners()[0];
adapter.windowClosing(new WindowEvent(daughterWindow, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two visual elements created in the provided fragment of the code:

`JDialog daughterWindow = new JDialog();`

and

`JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();`

Both of them defined as modal. Which basically means -- while one is active, other is not active, not even has a possibility to gain control.

I suggest you set your `daughterWindow.setModal(false);`

and move

```
open.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

daughterWindow.setResizable(false);
daughterWindow.pack();
daughterWindow.setVisible(true);         

if(open.showOpenDialog(daughterWindow) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
```

Update. It is not obvious from the code that file dialog is modal, but as per Java Doc it is:

`File choosers provide a GUI for navigating the file system, and then either choosing a file or directory from a list, or entering the name of a file or directory. To display a file chooser, you usually use the JFileChooser API to show a modal dialog containing the file chooser.`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: First of all thank you for the clue! I've tried to play around with the modality of the `daughterWndow` element and to en- and disable it in various quarters, alas without any noticeable effect. Furthermore I attempted to treat the case after `if(open.showOpenDialog(daughterWindow) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)` or maybe it was pointless at all?

Comment: Make sure you show `daughterWindow` before you open modal file choose dialog, not after.

Comment: That's it! In this case we shouldn't only set `daughterWindow` visible at all, otherwise it would appear two times in a row. Thank you very much!